# Configuring JSONCPP with cococ2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I ma using cocos2d-x with eclipse on mac osx. I am trying to configure JSON cpp into my cocos2d-X game. Can anyone tell me how i can integrate the library into my project ?

Answer (score 0):

`Cocos2d-x 2.2` and earlier versions has already support for jsoncpp library and it is used in Cocos2d-x extensions. Just check the Coco-Studio examples in `TestCpp` project.

Or you can take reference from `extensions\CocoStudio\Reader\SceneReader.cpp` which reads json file to load a scene.